# Boolean($var) VS $val ? true : false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Q. Which is more READABLE ?**

```js
const emptyValue = "";

Boolean(emptyValue);
// false
```

**VS**

```js
const emptyValue = "";

emptyValue ? true : false;
// false
```

This is a very common case in which you want the flow changes according to a specific value of a variable.
I know this has almost no difference in a matter of performance, but I'm really curious about the option of the community in a matter of READABILITY.

Comment: I'd say !!emptyValue is even better than those alternatives.

Comment: Depends on skill level. The `? true : false;` should be considered readable on any skill level. It takes a bit of throught what the conversion to another data type will do.

Comment: Really depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion is more readable the second, namely:

```
const emptyValue = "";

emptyValue ? true : false;
```

but the javascript way to convert in a Boolean type is:

```
const emptyValue = "";

!!emptyValue;
```

`!` calls Boolean() behind the hood, thereby is called twice and is less efficient than the single Boolean() solution, but I repeat is the javascript way.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer just to test the variable name

It works for ALL except 0 if you need to test a number - for that you can use [!! Double Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!)

> It is possible to use a couple of NOT operators in series to explicitly force the conversion of any value to the corresponding boolean primitive. The conversion is based on the "truthyness" or "falsyness" of the value

```js
const emptyValue = "";
let undefinedValue;
const zero = 0;
const nullValue = null
const definedVariable = "Hello"

console.log(definedVariable,emptyValue,undefinedValue,zero,nullValue)

console.log(Boolean(definedVariable), Boolean(emptyValue),Boolean(undefinedValue),Boolean(zero),Boolean(nullValue))
console.log(!!definedVariable ,!!emptyValue,!!undefinedValue,!!zero,!!nullValue)

if (definedVariable) console.log("definedVariable is truthy");
if (!emptyValue) console.log("emptyValue is falsy");
if (!undefinedValue) console.log("undefinedValue is falsy");
if (!zero) console.log("zero is falsy"); 
if (!!zero) console.log("zero is not falsy with !!"); 
if (!nullValue) console.log("nullValue is falsy");
```